# How to adjust the output of dbus-monitor?

Tags: bash, shell-script, d-bus, ipc

I'm building a microservices application using the GNU tools and bash and I decided to use `dbus-monitor` and `dbus-send` for IPC between services.
The problem is that it's hard to make use of the messages received by `dbus-monitor` since it splits metadata and payload in different lines.

If I instantiate a listener with

```
dbus-monitor --system interface=org.foo.bar member=test \
 | while read a; do
  echo got message $a
done
```

and communicate to it with

```
dbus-send --system --type=signal / org.foo.bar.test string:"hello world"
```

The output comes as

```
got line signal time=1676042614.782238 path=; interface=org.foo.bar; member=test
got line string "hello world"
```

even though `string "hello world"` is the payload to the message, it was written in a different line.

I tried messing with IFS but no success. I also tried to change parameters to `dbus-monitor`, but the parameter `--profile` omits the payload. So I dont know how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Add "type=string" as an expression to the end of the dbus-monitor command if you only want strings.